# Segmentation fault (core dumped) при вводе относительно длинной строки

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы, malloc, realloc

У меня есть функция создания динамического массива ввода строки, в нее я кладу &ссылку на указатель типа char.
**Проблема**: для небольших строк длиной примерно 15 символов или около того все отлично работает, но если в строке, к примеру, 200 символов - програма падает с ошибкой **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

**Почему?** Заранее спасибо!

```
int create_array(char** arr){
     char capacity = 2, tmp;
     int i = 0;
     (*arr) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * capacity);
     while ( (tmp = getchar()) != '\n' && tmp != EOF ){
         *(*arr + i) = tmp;
         i++; // запись размера
         if (i == capacity){
             capacity *= 2;
             (*arr) = (char*)realloc((*arr), sizeof(char) * capacity); // расширяю массив
         }
     }
     return i; // возврат размера
}
```

Comment: а отладиться? санитайзеры включить там? core еще есть)

Comment: я не знаю таких слов, извините

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Глупая ошибка - у вас `capacity` в `char` хранится, доходит до 127, потом преполнение и кирдык.

Comment: это диагноз))))) спасибо!

Comment: Я бы еще посоветовал перед return записывать в строку терминирующий 0 // И еще, наверное имеет смысл все же записывать в строку и '\n' (иначе возникнут проблемы у вызывающей стороны, если последняя строка файла не имеет '\n')